# How can I convert PyArray into Vec<Vec<T>> in Rust

Tags: python, rust, numpy-ndarray, pyo3

I am using the numpy crate in Rust to work with 2D arrays that come from python. `PyArray` (https://docs.rs/numpy/0.11.0/numpy/array/struct.PyArray.html) implements a `from_vec2()` function, which converts a `Vec<Vec<T>>` into a `PyArray<T, 2>` (2D PyArray), and a `to_vec()` function, which flattens the 2D array into a 1D vector and returns `Vec<T>`, but it does not implement `to_vec2()`. Is there a simple way to do this conversion which I am missing, or would I have to implement this function by hand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.iter`](https://docs.rs/numpy/0.13.0/numpy/array/struct.PyArray.html#method.iter) along with some iterator methods to do this:

```py
arr.iter().unwrap().map(|arr| arr.to_vec().unwrap()).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

Comment: Unfortunately .iter() forces conversion into a vector first, and so you are once again left with the 2D array flattened into a 1D array, thus the elements that you are mapping over are not themselves arrays.

Comment: @Yaxlat There's an `iter` defined for `PyArray`s, and you map `to_vec` on each element two get a 2d vector.

Comment: I did try this, but ```iter``` flattens the ```PyArray``` so the elements are just going to floats or integers or whatever, rather than arrays that you could apply ```to_vec``` to. Your code just gives an error which says that type f64 does not have a method called ```to_vec```. I've just implemented this manually for now but it is pretty messy. Thanks for the help anyway!